# scrapy selenium pagination

Tags: python, selenium, pagination, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape [tripadvisor's website](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147288-Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html). I used 2 approaches , the first one is by using **CrawlSpiders** and **Rules**. Not so satisfied with the result, i'm now trying to use **Selenium** to go through each links. The only problem being the pagination issue. I want the selenium browser to go open the webpage and go through each link in the starturl and then click the next page on the bottom. So far i've written code only to extract the required content as:

```
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    div_val = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="tab_contents"]')
    for link in div_val:
        l = link.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
        if re.match(r'http:\/\/www\.tripadvisor\.com\/Hotels\-g[\d]*\-Dominican\_Republic\-Hotels\.html',l):
            link.click()
            time.sleep(5)

                try:
                    hotel_links = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="listing_title"]')
                    for hotel_link in hotel_links:
                        lnk = hotel_link.find_element_by_class_name('property_title').get_attribute('href')

                except NoSuchElementException:
                    print 'elemenotfound
```

I'm now stuck with pagination with selenium.

Comment: You can automate on clicking on the next button and giving a pause in between requests .I think it will work well for you. If I am correct do you want to enter each link like the listing and extract data and then completing all the pages you want to click on the next button?

Answer (score 1):

I think a mix of `CrawlSpider` and `Selenium` will work for you -

```
for click in range(0,15):#clicking on next button for pagination
    button = self.driver.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[7]/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[41]/div[2]/div/a")

    button.click()

    time.sleep(10)

    for i in range(0,10):#range depends upon number of listings you can change it# for entering into the individual url using response
            item['url'] = response.xpath('a[contains(@class,"property_title ")]/@href').extract()[i]
            if item['url']:
                                                    if 'http://' not in item['url']:
                                                        item['url'] = urljoin(response.url, item['url'])
                                                    yield scrapy.Request(item['url'],
                                                                        meta={'item': item},
                                                                        callback=self.anchor_page)


                def anchor_page(self, response):

                    old_item = response.request.meta['item']

                    data you want to scrape
                    yield old_item
```